# "Write in the language you are writing" or "... you are writing in"?

Tags: word-choice

So, I'm watching [this lecture](http://vimeo.com/25606006). One of the slides (at minute 27) in that lecture contains this sentence:

> "Write in the language you are writing."

But shouldn't it be:

> "Write in the language you are writing in."

It's about a programming language. Programmers *write in* that programming language. They do not *write* that programming language.

[image: Screenshot from Crockford's lecture]

Comment: Or, "Write in the language in which you are writing."

Comment: @Chris Yes, that sounds good.

Comment: or, "Write the language you write", if we want to be a bit more minimalist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we *can* say "write Perl" (or PHP, or for that matter, French) as well as "write in Perl", there's nothing wrong with 1.

But 2 is certainly more symmetrical, and it's what I would write.

Comment: In most contexts I would say that repetition of "in" is distractingly "ugly". But such considerations don't need to apply to "motivational slogans" like this, so you're right - it gains more from the symmetry than it loses from the unusual phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct. I wouldn't use the sentence shown in the slide.